# Why does coffeescript need to be installed globally?

Tags: npm, coffeescript, npm-install

I have a jenkins build that is failing with the following error:

> + npm install
>
> npm WARN prefer global coffee-script@1.12.4 should be installed with -g

Curious as to why coffee-script, or any package for that matter, needs to be installed globally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `coffeescript` is a command line tool which can transpile coffeescript into javascript, or run as as an interactive shell similar to `node`.

from the [NPMJS docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/installing-npm-packages-globally):

> There are two ways to install npm packages: locally or globally. You choose which kind of installation to use based on how you want to use the package.
>
> If you want to use it as a command line tool, something like the grunt CLI, then you want to install it globally. On the other hand, if you want to depend on the package from your own module using something like Node's require, then you want to install locally.

It would technically be possible to install these CLI packages locally, but then you would have to run them using a relative path such as(untested):

```
./node_modules/coffeescript/bin/coffeescript
```